# How to add PM or AM based on hour from input?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a clock with some functions. Now, I get the result from clock in that input :

```
  <input class="arrow tag-input tag-input-mobile" type='Number' id='number2' placeholder='7:00 PM' class='qty' max="10" min="0" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalTime"/>
```

I'm getting only the value from clock, but I need to have PM/AM, based on that value, how can I add it with JavaScript?

**Here is my code:**

```js
function increaseValue() {
  var value = parseInt(document.getElementById('number').value, 10);
  value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
  value++;
  if (value > 24) {
    return
  }
  document.getElementById('number').value = value;
  document.getElementById('number2').value = value;
}

function decreaseValue() {
  var value = parseInt(document.getElementById('number').value, 10);
  value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
  value < 1 ? value = 1 : '';
  value--;
  document.getElementById('number').value = value;
  document.getElementById('number2').value = value;
}

function maxLengthCheck(object) {
  if (object.value.length > object.maxLength)
    object.value = object.value.slice(0, object.maxLength)
}

function isNumeric(evt) {
  var theEvent = evt || window.event;
  var key = theEvent.keyCode || theEvent.which;
  key = String.fromCharCode(key);
  var regex = /[0-9]|\./;
  if (!regex.test(key)) {
    theEvent.returnValue = false;
    if (theEvent.preventDefault) theEvent.preventDefault();
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalTime" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">




      <div class="wrapper-clock" id="wrapper">
        <div id="navigator">

          <div id="calendar">

            <div id="daysblock3">

              <div class="bottom-items">

                <img class="bg-clock" src="images/clock/bg-clock.png">
                <img class="left-up" src="images/clock/left-up.png" id="increase" onclick="increaseValue()" value="Increase Value">
                <img class="right-up" src="images/clock/right-up.png" id="increaseR" onclick="increaseValueR()" value="Increase ValueR">
                <img class="right-down" src="images/clock/right-down.png" id="decreaseR" onclick="decreaseValueR()" value="Decrease Value">
                <img class="left-down" src="images/clock/left-down.png" id="decrease" onclick="decreaseValue()" value="Decrease Value">
                <img class="line-time" src="images/clock/line.png">

                <p class="text-pm">PM</p>
                <input class="text-hour" type='Number' id='number' value='7' class='qty' max="10" min="0" maxlength="2" oninput="maxLengthCheck(this)" />
                <input class="text-minutes" type='Number' id='numberR' value='00' class='qty' max="10" min="0" maxlength="2" oninput="maxLengthCheckR(this)" />

              </div>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>


      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

So, I need to add that kind of text only in that input `document.getElementById('number2').value = value;` So, from 0 to 12 should have AM, and from 13 to 24 it should be PM.

Comment: Like you described with words, you need somewhere in your JS `if (value>12) then do smt else do smt...`

Comment: Note that the `<input>` tag does not need and does not use a closing slash and never has in HTML.

Comment: @Rob I know, but it helps me to see better where is final > .

Comment: @ThanhTrung how can I add that `if (value > 12)` ... maybe with value +  'AM' `else` value+ 'PM'?

Comment: @Andrew Needing to know where a self closing tag that has no content ends is just another problem altogether. Putting that there is just "tag soup" and not called for in any HTML specification

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need something like this. I have allowed 24 hours in max value input, but then in javascript I substract 12 hours if it's in PM. As you can see, it is possible check the value of an input without parsing it to `int`. Finally, you concatenate PM or AM to your result.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var value = document.getElementById('number').value;

  if (value > 12) {
    value = value - 12;
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = value + "PM";
  } else {
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = value + "AM";
  }
}
```

```html
<input type='Number' id='number' max="24" min="0" value="0">

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button><br>
<p id="result"></p>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use select method also. Here is the example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<select id="mySelect" onchange="myFunction()">
  <option value=0>0</option>
  <option value=1>1</option>
  <option value=2>2</option>
  <option value=3>3</option>
  <option value=4>4</option>
  <option value=5>5</option>
  <option value=6>6</option>
  <option value=7>7</option>
  <option value=8>8</option>
  <option value=9>9</option>
  <option value=10>10</option>
  <option value=11>11</option>
  <option value=12>12</option>
  <option value=13>13</option>
  <option value=14>14</option>
  <option value=15>15</option>
  <option value=16>16</option>
  <option value=17>17</option>
  <option value=18>18</option>
  <option value=19>19</option>
  <option value=20>20</option>
  <option value=21>21</option>
  <option value=22>22</option>
  <option value=23>23</option>
  <option value=24>24</option>

  
</select>

<p id="Clockresult">0AM</p>  
  
<script>




function myFunction() {

  var value = document.getElementById('mySelect').value;

  if (value > 12) {
    value = value - 12;
    document.getElementById('Clockresult').innerHTML = value + "PM";
  } else {
    document.getElementById('Clockresult').innerHTML = value + "AM";
  }
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("input").change(function(){
    
    var value = document.getElementById('number').value;
    if (value > 12) {
      value = value - 12;
      document.getElementById('Clockresult').innerHTML = value + "PM";
    } else {
      document.getElementById('Clockresult').innerHTML = value + "AM";
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<input type='text' id='number'>
<p id="Clockresult">Time</p>

</body>
</html>
```